# rsyslogd eating up 20+ GB (!) of RAM - what evidence to gather?

Tags: rsyslog, memory-leaks

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.3 box running kernel 3.13.0-74 with 32GB RAM, which features a rsyslogd process gone mad:

```
$ ps -auxww | grep rsyslog
syslog   16212  0.7 64.0 27966168 21070336 ?   Ssl  Jan04 180:31 rsyslogd -c 5 -x

$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32142      31863        278        228          9        363
-/+ buffers/cache:      31490        651
Swap:        16383      11937       4446
```

I know ps' output cannot be fully relied on etc but surely that's a bit high!  I also have two sibling machines with the same s/w (running since the same time) and on both siblings, rsyslogd is behaving better (it's still using about 3.5GB on each).

This is rsyslogd 7.4.4 and I understand that a [memory leak was fixed in a newer version](http://www.rsyslog.com/changelog-for-7-5-5-v7-devel/).

**My question:** before I rush to upgrade, I'd like to gather some evidence to show that I've indeed hit that leak, if possible.  I've left the rsyslogd running for now but it won't be long until it churns all the swap so need to act reasonably soon...

One thing I have collecting evidence is `atop`.  This clearly shows when the leak started occurring (and I don't recall doing anything special to the box at that time).  What's interesting is that at the same time as memory starts to grow, disk write activity plummets - though it doesn't stop completely.  The filesystem is fine capacity-wise.

```
$ atop -r atop_20160117 | grep rsyslogd
  PID  SYSCPU  USRCPU  VGROW  RGROW  RDDSK  WRDSK ST EXC S  CPU CMD            
16212   0.03s   0.06s     0K     0K     0K    96K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.11s   0.22s     0K     0K     0K  1844K --   - S   2% rsyslogd       
16212   0.03s   0.12s     0K     0K     0K   564K --   - S   1% rsyslogd       
16212   0.04s   0.06s     0K     0K     0K    96K --   - S   1% rsyslogd       
16212   0.08s   0.19s     0K     0K     0K  1808K --   - S   1% rsyslogd       
16212   0.04s   0.11s     0K     0K     0K   608K --   - S   1% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.07s     0K     0K     0K   116K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.06s   0.04s     0K  2640K     0K   144K --   - S   1% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.02s     0K  1056K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.01s   0.01s     0K   264K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.04s     0K  2904K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.02s     0K  1056K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.00s     0K   264K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.06s   0.09s 75868K  3532K   208K     0K --   - S   1% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.02s     0K   792K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.01s   0.01s     0K   264K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.05s   0.03s     0K  3168K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.02s     0K  1056K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.00s   0.01s     0K   264K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.03s   0.10s     0K  2904K     0K     0K --   - S   1% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.02s     0K   792K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.00s   0.02s     0K   264K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.04s   0.03s     0K  2904K     0K   160K --   - S   0% rsyslogd       
16212   0.02s   0.02s     0K   792K     0K     0K --   - S   0% rsyslogd
```

**edit:** here's the free memory graph from Zabbix for that box; the start of the decline at about 9:30 on 17-Jan coincides with `atop`'s output above.

[image: Zabbix available memory graph (8d)]

**final edit:** I had to restart that `rsyslogd`; it freed up a whooping 20 GB, confirming - if there was any doubt - that it was the culprit:

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32142      11325      20817        282         56        473
-/+ buffers/cache:      10795      21347
Swap:        16383       5638      10745
```

Alas, after running only 12 hours, it's now back to over 4GB.  Clearly something's not right; I'll have to try the upgrade path...

Comment: I am only seeing 20 something MB in syslog

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: if it's the `ps`output you're referring to, it's in KB according to man, so this is indeed 20+ GB.  top is being a little more explicit:
`PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND`
`16212 syslog    20   0 28.046g 0.020t    960 S   0.7 64.2 181:28.67 rsyslogd`.
It's the first time I'm seeing top reporting a mem size with a 't'!

Comment: vmstat is also a good command to collect evidences. we use here cacti for long term monitoring

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thanks for the suggestion.  `vmstat` agrees with `free -m`; could you elaborate on what I should be looking for?

Comment: apt-get install memstat ; memstat

Comment: I am afraid you either have history data or dont...beside these commands not pretty much to add...that is the main reason we maintain data taken with SNMP from our servers, to build a baseline

Comment: Thanks @RuiFRibeiro. `memstat`reports the same crazy virtual memory usage for PID 16212 as what can be seen in `ps` and `top`.  Your point about "history data" reminded me that we do keep that in a Zabbix server (which is what alerted me to the fact that over 50% of the swap was consumed).  Zabbix's free memory graph agrees with `atop`...

Comment: my own example, my team was reboot it every week and did not tell me...before and after I solved the "leak" http://imgur.com/bEjTN0F

Comment: I had a similar issue with rsyslog version 8.24.0 on Redhat 4.8.5-11 - using 5 GB memory -- 30% of total memory.

Answer (score 6):

The file `/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.services`

```
[Service]
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryCurrent=8192000
MemoryLimit=8192000
```

Comment: It might be worth saying that this is an attempt to *limit* the resources rsyslog uses, as opposed to the Question's focus "what evidence to gather"

Comment: It might be worth including a verb or two in your answer, and ideally some explanation.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: And where might that `rsyslog.services` file live on Red Hat 4.8.5-11?

Comment: This file doesn't exist in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Locate the unit file on any systemd distro with `systemctl cat rsyslog.service`

Answer (score 2):

In my case (a centos 7 server), restarting the `rsyslog` service worked quite well! `rsyslogd` process **RESIDENT** memory usage dropped from 5gb to 9mb!

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```